# Overhead of calling c++/cx function from c# sometimes increases drasticly

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cx, overhead

I've noticed wird behaviour in my application, and I can't understand why it's happening.

I have a C# method(lets call it methodC#) that I call very often. In the body of this method there is only one instruction which is a call to a c++/cx method(lets call it methodCx).

Average execution time of methodCx is less than 1ms. 
Average execution time of methodC# is 3ms.

This means that average overhead of calling methodCx from C# is around 3ms.

Sometimes, when the load of my application is high(due to computations done on other threads), this overhead can jump even to 80ms. I can't understand why this is happening. I know that due to the load, code execution can slow down, but it seems that only calling cx methods from c# have increased so drasticly. Non c# -> cx calls seems not affected(at least not so drasticaly). Can someone explain this behaviour. At least maybe a hint where to search for a culprit.

Thanks in advance

Edit1
methodCx takes 3 separate floats as parameters. It returns Cx object.

Edit2
I used Stopwatch for timing in C# and performance counter for timing in c++/cx. Results are the same. Execution time of methodCx is few hundreds of microseconds while execution time of methodC# can go up to even 100ms during high load on other threads.

Comment: How are you timing this? I'm guessing the marshalling is slowing down for some reason (depending on what parameter types you're passing, it may have to do some memory allocations etc)

Comment: Execution time is few microseconds so its less than 0ms. For timing I use substraction of DateTime.Now objects.

Comment: DateTime.Now is extremely inaccurate for timing short periods. You must use Stopwatch instead.

Comment: read [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two): part Mistake #5: Using a clock instead of a stopwatch.

Comment: Less than 0ms - this is really fast...

Comment: WinRT is built on top of COM.  Which provides automatic thread-safety for apartment threaded objects by marshaling the call from a worker thread to the thread that created the object.  That's expensive.  Short from the double thread context switch, the latency in the thread that owns the object is usually by far the most noticeable overhead.  Milliseconds are possible.